# SSIS ODBC Source Previews Data But Fails When Executing Package

Tags: ssis, odbc

This is really odd to me.  I am using an ODBC connection as a data source in SSIS.  I am able to preview data, but when I attempt to execute the package (still within Visual Studio for development), I get an error on the initial data source.

The error I am receiving is:

```
There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.

The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager xxx failed with error code 0xC0014009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

ODBC Source failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.
```

Clearly I have the right username, password, and ODBC connection to some degree, because I am able to see the data.  However I am failing on establishing the connection when I attempt to run the package, so I must be doing something wrong.  Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Smells like it's losing the credentials between design and run-time mode. Assume it's an explicit user and password versus integrated authentication? What is the package protection level (default will be `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`)? Are the the package author or just a maintainer?

Comment: Yeah, it's an explicit user and password, not integrated auth.  I am the author and testing out a new connection.  At the moment, it's using the default EncryptSenesitiveWithUserKey.

Comment: As a quick hack. create two SSIS Variables, userid and password and put in the credentials. Right click on your Connection Manager and choose Properties. Click the ellipses `...` on Expressions and add one for User name and one for Password and use your variables as the values. Save. Close and reopen the package and in the data flow, confirm that preview still works for the source. If so, run it and see whether it behaves any different

Comment: I thought I'd follow up with you on this one.  It ended up being that the drivers associated with the ODBC connection (gsk8ssl.dll) installed on the machine needed to be added to the path variables on both my local and on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that the drivers associated with the ODBC connection (gsk8ssl.dll) installed on the machine needed to be added to the path variables on both my local and on the server.  This was for connecting to a DB2 database.